# How to Draw 3D Geometry Shapes Using PHP?

Tags: php, gd

There is a situation where I need to draw cube or cuboid using the PHP GD library. Does anyone know where to find a simple example or a PHP class to do this?

Thank you for any reference.

Comment: Look up some articles on software 3D rendering.

Comment: Have you got GD working? If so, do as HyperCas says.

Comment: I did a search and found http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3364-PHP-Compose-and-render-3D-object-models.html where one could easily create a cube but not a cuboid. The method accepts only width and height, where we need width, depth and height for a cuboid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://web.archive.org/web/20080514162633/http://www.devmaster.net/articles/software-rendering/part1.php
- http://web.archive.org/web/20080509174752/http://www.devmaster.net/articles/software-rendering/part2.php

This should get you started on basic 3d rendering in software. You can use simple GD functions to draw basic 3D shapes easily.

Comment: Thank you HyperCas. I shall go through the articles and try to implement it myself. Those two links are precious.

Comment: But I must say, the links are broken.